# Include Vue in a Codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js

I have a very broad project, developed in codeigniter, I want to integrate Vue and I do not know how to do it.

Is it better to create a new project based on Vue and try to migrate things?

Modify my JS of my current project and replace it with Vue?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrontEnd frameworks has nothing to do backend frameworks. They communicate via http-request responses.
You may use backend of your choice and render the content on the page.

However, if you want to integrate vue with existing project (which is already working), I recommend new project based on Vue and migrate back end code on need basis

Comment: I think migrate to a new Vue structure isn't helpful since could exists very long and heavy projects. Migrating to a new Vue structure might be insane.

Answer (score 2):

i have sucessfully use vue to replace codeigniter view layer, i use laravel mixin to compile vue SFC then include built file to the codeigniter view template